# Alternative to absolute positioning that updates parents height

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a library that draws brackets.

I am calculating the coordinates of each element (matches and lines) using javascript. Each element has `position: absolute;` and uses `left` and `top` to set their `x` and `y` coordinates.

Because I am using `position: absolute;` it is necessary to set the parent to `position: relative;` so that the children are positioned relative to their parent.

[image]

This was working perfectly until I noticed that the parents height was not updating from its children, because `position: absolute;` elements are taken out of the flow of the document.

I need the parent to have height so that I can place other elements underneath, and give the parent styles such as `background-color`...

1. Is there an alternative to absolute positioning that uses x and y coordinates but also keeps them in the flow of the document to allow the parents `width` and `height` to adjust automatically?
2. Or, if that is not possible, is there away using vanilla javascript (no jQuery or other libraries) to find out the width and height of the contents of the parent div. If this is possible I can just set the parent's `width` and `height` styles through javascript.

**What I've tried so far**

1. I tried to set the children to `position: relative;` instead of `position: absolute;` which I believe would work if you only have one child. However, with more than one child, the children are not relative to the parent but are now relative to the previous child which messes things up.

[image]

2. Even though the parent has no height there is still a vertical scrollbar on the page. Using javascript, I tried to get the `scrollHeight` and `height` of elements such as `document`, `document.body` and `window`. This did not work because either the result was `undefined` or the result was incorrect.

Right now my **temporary solution** is to set `body` height to `2500px` which should be the highest it will ever need to be. The problem with this is that there will always be a scrollbar, most of the time scrolling to nothing.

**Code**

```
<div class="BrackChart_wrapper">
    <div class="BrackChart_match"> ... </div>
    <div class="BrackChart_line"></div>
    etc.
</div>

.BrackChart_wrapper {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}

.BrackChart_match, .BrackChart_line {
    position: absolute;
}
```

Thank you for the help, much appreciated!

**JSFiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/jmjcocq8/1/

**Solution**: https://jsfiddle.net/jmjcocq8/2/

Comment: You can position elements with `left:` and `top:` css attributes on relative positioned elements, not just absolute ones.

Comment: @pokeybit: The OP addresses that in the post above, and describes why it isn't working for him.

Comment: good question, I would also like if someone answer it using CSS only. If possible.

Comment: Apologies @David

Comment: A fiddle would be good for this kind of question

Comment: Seems flexbox would work fine.. hard to tell without a minimal example.

Comment: @abeyaz I will try to make a minimized JSFiddle without any javascript.

Comment: @abeyaz & David - Not a fiddle, a Stack Snippet so the whole thing is here on-site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm fairly sure there's no alternative that both lets you position the children absolutely (relative to their parent) and keeps them in the flow such that they contribute to the size of the parent.

But since you're calculating the positions of the elements yourself, and you know how tall they are, you can set the height of the parent based on the lowest child's y plus height.

You haven't shown your code, but for instance:

```js
var forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
function positionChildren(parent) {
  var left = 0;
  var top = 0;
  forEach.call(parent.children, function(child, index) {
    child.style.left = left + "px";
    child.style.top = top + "px";
    left += 20;
    top += 10;
  });
  var height = top - 10 + 1 + parent.lastElementChild.clientHeight;
  console.log("height = " + height);
  parent.style.height = height + "px";
}

positionChildren(document.getElementById("parent"));
```

```css
#parent {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #ddd;
  position: relative;
}
.child {
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="child">Child1</div>
  <div class="child">Child2</div>
  <div class="child">Child3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is what I was thinking myself and I will do this if there is no easier solution. Thanks for the input.

Comment: Thank you, this works! Every time I create an element I just check if its `y` is higher than the current highest, if so I update the highest to `y`. Then I set the height of the parent to `y` + height of child element (match).